# Prevent double action on modal save

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following code

```
$('#modal').dialog("option", "buttons", {
    Save: SaveMethod,
    Cancel: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
});
```

When I click the Save button many times very quickly (even if I set the button as `disabled='disabled'`) the `SaveMethod` function still runs several times. How can I prevent the button click until the first method call has ended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable outside of your `SaveMethod` scope to keep track of when you are saving could work.

If `SaveMethod` completes quickly you may still be able to click the button multiple times.  In that case you could set `saving = false` in your dialog close event or maybe replace `saving = false` with `setTimeout(function(){ saving = false; }, 500);` to delay a bit before allowing saving again.

```
$('#modal').dialog("option", "buttons", {
    Save: SaveMethod,
    Cancel: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
});

var saving = false;

function SaveMethod(){
  if(saving) return;
  saving = true;
  //save code
  saving = false;
}
```